# Index Error when using microbit module in MicroPython

Tags: python, python-3.x, micropython

Currently trying to develop a small two-button game for the BBC micro:bit. Since the micro:kit is not widely available, I will try to explain my problem in detail.

I am trying to create the controls for the player, a 'movable' light that is stuck on the last row of the grid. The A button is supposed to move the light one column left, and the B button is supposed to move the light 1 column right.

I have created 5 separate images *(called **player_loc#**)* for the matrix, each one being a possible location for the LED.

```
from microbit import *
import random

player_index = 2

player_loc0 = Image('00000:00000:00000:00000:50000')
player_loc1 = Image('00000:00000:00000:00000:05000')
player_loc2 = Image('00000:00000:00000:00000:00500')
player_loc3 = Image('00000:00000:00000:00000:00050')
player_loc4 = Image('00000:00000:00000:00000:00005')

player_locs = [player_loc0, player_loc1, player_loc2, player_loc3, player_loc4]
# Indexes            0             1           2             3            4

while True:
    display.show(player_locs[player_index])
    if button_a.is_pressed():
        player_index += 1
    elif button_b.is_pressed():
        player_index -= 1
```

The A button is supposed to subtract 1 from **player_index** (equal to 2), thereby making **display.show(player_locs[player_index])** display Image **player_loc1** instead of **player_loc2**.
   The B button does the opposite, it adds one, which should result in **player_loc3** being displayed.

---

The problem I'm having is that when I press the A or B button, I get an IndexError, list index is out of range, on Line 17,  **display.show(player_locs[player_index])**. The index should in no way be out of range. On the list **player_locs**, I have indexes ranging from 0-4. Indexes 1 and 3 aren't out of range, yet it displays the IndexError out of range message. When I remove player_index, and run it with any integer 0-4, it works.

---

Here is an image of when I run the script without pushing any buttons. As soon as a button is pressed, the error message shows.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[LEDpicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYbH7.jpg)

Comment: Are you `if` statements passing? Is `button_x.is_pressed()` actually working as expected? Additionally, does `.is_pressed` hold the loop for a response, or does it just let the loop run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the [is_pressed](http://microbit-micropython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/button.html#Button.is_pressed) method on a while loop without any delays, so basically what happens is that the loop will execute really quick and have enough time to iterate several times while you press any of the buttons, even if you perceived the press to be really quick. In each of these iterations the loop reads the button state as pressed, and it increases or decreases the player_index enough times to get it outside of its valid range.

Alternatively you can use the [was_pressed](http://microbit-micropython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/button.html#Button.was_pressed), which tracks individual presses and will work the way you expect it.

If you want to make sure your index is never out of range you can even add additional checks to ensure the program doesn't crash:

```
while True:
    display.show(player_locs[player_index])
    if button_a.was_pressed() and player_index < (len(player_locs) - 1):
        player_index += 1
    elif button_b.was_pressed() and player_index > 0:
        player_index -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am an amateur, so I'm still learning. I scrapped my old code, because I was frustrated from getting stuck so early on. I came up with a more "integer based" script rather than using preset images that change. I thought that using simple integers would allow for easier control flow use, manipulation of integers (and therefore images) rather than having to alter and test images. I was also thinking of creating a calculator with this using the two buttons, so the advice will come in handy. Thanks for helping me out though!

---

Here is the updated code in case you're wondering. I am currently trying to add the random enemy/wall generation:

```
from microbit import *
import random

game_over == False

player_x = 2
player_y = 4
#starting coords for 'player' pixel

light = 5
wall_light = 7
#brightness. self explanatory

wall_pos_x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
wall_y = 0
#all possible coords of wall. y coords
#are changed in function

#generates enemy wall with a randomly generated hole
def enemy_wall():

    open_x = random.randint(0,4)
    open_y = 0

    for wall_xs in range(open_x-1, open_x, -1)
        wall_pos_x[wall_xs]
        pass
    #for loops will iterate over all possible x coords except
    #the open hole's coords. for loop will use iteration and
    #display all possible x coords except open_x.

def player(x, y, bright):

    if x <= -1:
        x = 0
    elif x >= 5:
        x = 4
    display.set_pixel(x,y,bright)
    return x
    #if x coord is +- 1 more than available coords,
    #doesnt move/change position at edge

#updated newer player control. push of button changes x coord by -+ 1
#cannot change y coord
while game_over != True:

    player(player_x,player_y,light)
    sleep(750)
    #player coords re/displayed, and button cooldown 750ms

    if button_a.is_pressed():
        player_x = player(player_x-1,player_y,light)
        display.clear()
        #runs through player(), then clears display of
        #previous pixel *player*.
    elif button_b.is_pressed():
        player_x = player(player_x+1,player_y,light)
        display.clear()
```